# Квартальная репутация больше полной

Tags: дефект, репутация

[Пример](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/609/quarter/ru-stackoverflow/2023-01-01/533449?sort=reputationchange#533449).

> [image: Репутация за квартал больше общей]

Это какая-то экстраполяция?

Comment: Это chatGPTшник. Скорее всего такие цифры вызваны удалением его постов. Видимо набранное суммируется, но не отнимается...